# Loop through buttons on webpage selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am stuck at looping through elements (which are buttons)

```
eleButtons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and contains(@onclick,'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2')]")

for ele in eleButtons:
    print(ele.get_attribute("onlick"))
```

The output are None for the print lines. That's a point and when trying to click a button using this line, it works for just one button

```
ele.click()
```

After the click event, another page loaded and I couldn't loop through the rest of buttons although I could go back to the page that contains the buttons using this line

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button2').click()")
```

The html of a button looks like that

```
<input type="button" value="TheSelect" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView2','Select$1')">
```

And the outer html of each button is different at one part only which is this `Select$1`, `Select$2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the buttons change all the time and I have used the following trick to be able to loop successfully

```
eleButtons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and contains(@onclick,'Select$0')]")

while True:
    if len(eleButtons) != 1:
        break
    eleButtons[0].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    eleStatus = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownList1']")
    selectStatus = Select(eleStatus)
    selectStatus.select_by_visible_text('Accept')
    time.sleep(1)
    eleSave = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button_save']")
    eleSave.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button2').click()")
    time.sleep(2)
    eleButtons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='button' and contains(@onclick,'Select$0')]")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is this the solution to above question  ? or do you still need assistance  ?

Comment: Yes, it is the solution for me but I welcome any other ideas.